# Why does google picker duplicated files?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-picker

Currently when uploading a file duplicates occur if the file already exists. I'm using the hello world sample that google provides.

I was expecting the revision feature to work but sadly this is not the case.

Is this the default behaviour of google picker or I'm doing something wrong?

```
function createPicker() {
    if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {

    //let view = new google.picker.DocsView().setParent('FOLDER_ID');
    let uploadView = new google.picker.DocsUploadView().setParent('FOLDER_ID');

    let picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
            //.addView(view)
            .addView(uploadView)
            .hideTitleBar()
            .setAppId(appId)
            .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
            .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of Google Picker which is what happens in the real world when you upload a file which currently exists as is with all programs including downloads. I think you understood revisions wrong. Read the [Manage Revisions guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-revisions) for clarification.

Comment: I see would it be possible to pass a callback that checks if a file selected for upload already exists?

Comment: you'd have to write a 'check if the file already exist' code  :)